# Designed database works properly in straight connection but not in 3 layer connection

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, database-connection

I have designed a website but in sign up section as for example new user, the user can't insert words only digit works in text box not words! And because of radio button(it's value is string) that is used to design this website I am no further along. The SQL Server 2016 with varchar (from 6 to 150 characters) datatypes and two integers is selected for this website and .NET 2015 is used for backend and also 3 layer structure is used for database.

for more information:

1. the system works in straight connection properly, with the same database but in 3 layer connection the error show's up.
2. While selected datatype is varchar(n) the system (for instance text box of the website) should accepts both digit and words not only digits!(other characters such as ',/,... works in straight connection too).
3. Here is the sample sign up class of business layer:

```
    public void Sign_Up()
    {
        base.Link();
        string Query = "INSERT INTO Table_User (FName, LName, EMail, Mobile, Adres, sex, Pass) VALUES ({0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6})";
        Query = string.Format(Query, FName, LName, EMail, Mobile, Adres, sex, Pass);
        base.CommandDataText(Query); 
        base.UnLink();
    }
```

The error:
[image]

the database is working properly in straight connection

Comment: A: you haven't told us what "works properly" means; what happens? What doesn't do what you expect? We're not psychic and we can't run the fragments of code here to find out; B: never concatenate or use string.Format against user input; use **parameters** - tools like Dapper can make this trivially easy; C: never store passwords - you should *cryptographically hash* them (salted) and store the hashes. This isn't just about the security of your system, it is about your users. Right now, your setup is an infosec nightmare: SQL injection and raw passwords.

Comment: By the way, the *immediate* problem appears to be lack of quotes on string values, but: **do not add them**: again, use parameters. These is no safe way of issuing such operations as a single simple string command. You need parameters.

Comment: Obligatory reference to [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/). Any time you feel like injecting tainted user data into an SQL query string... don't. Refer to the [SqlCommand.Parameters Property page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters#examples) for an example of how to use `SqlParameter`s with `SqlCommand` objects ... just ignore that pesky `AddWithValue()` usage there in the same example because that's bad practice.

Comment: [Back to basics: SQL Injection](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2020/07/16/back-to-basics-sql-injection/)

Comment: With the image now added: yes, the problem is exactly as I said - the lack of quotes for string literals, but again: **do not add them**: use parameters instead

Comment: It worked, thank you for advise, and i'll change the code to parameters  ASAP.